# Why are slices from String different from those hard coded as arguments to a function?

Tags: rust, ownership

I just finished reading "The Book" and I wanted to get started with a small project in Rust. I'm currently trying to make tests for a library which look like this:

```
pub mod api;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::env::var;

    fn create_blih<'a, 'b>() -> api::Blih<'a, 'b> {
        api::Blih::new("username", "password")
    }

    #[test]
    fn list_repositories() {
        create_blih().repository_list().unwrap();
    }

    ...
```

I wanted to remove my ids from the code and get them from environment variables so I changed my code like this:

```
fn create_blih<'a, 'b>() -> api::Blih<'a, 'b> {
    let user = var("blih_user").expect("set blih_user env var");
    let pass = var("blih_pass").expect("set blih_pass env var");
    api::Blih::new(&user, &pass)
}
```

My code doesn't compile with this error `error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable` for both variables.

I don't understand why the first `create_blih` works but not the second one because I use slices in both cases.

This may be of help:

```
pub struct Blih<'a, 'b> {
    base_url: &'b str,
    user: &'a str,
    user_agent: &'b str,
    password: &'a str,
    headers: HeaderMap,
}
```

```
impl<'a, 'b> Blih<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn new(user: &'a str, password: &'a str) -> Self
    ...
```

Thanks in advance helping me understand how ownership works!

Comment: in the first, you're using literals, which are hardcoded into the binary and are thus `'static`, (living for the life of the program). In the second case, you're using two `String`s which are dropped when the function scope ends (living for the life of the function).

Comment: @JoelBerkeley, you're response should be the answer here